# Showing real-time changes based on database changes from mysql in tkinter display in Python

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I have a table that is entirely made up of entry boxes in Tkinter that displays data from my MYSQL database. I want to update that display everytime the database is affected and by affected, I mean like new data was inserted to the database. Now when that new data gets inserted, I want to display that new data in the table but the problem is, the display does not update at all. Why is that?
Here's the code that focuses on the refresh feature of the program:

```py
    def update_employee_data():
        print("update_employee_data() working")
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees limit 0,10")
        result = cursor.fetchall()

        i = 0
        employee_subwindow.delete("all")  # Clear the existing contents of the canvas
        for employees in result:
            for j in range(len(employees)):
                table = Entry(employee_subwindow, font=("Century Gothic", 10), fg="black", background="white",
                              borderwidth=1.5, highlightthickness=1)
                table.config(state="normal")
                table.grid(row=i, column=j)
                table.insert(END, employees[j])
                table.config(state="readonly")
            i = i + 1

    # Define a refresh function to periodically update the GUI element(s)
    def refresh_employee_data():
        update_employee_data()
        win.after(10000,
                  refresh_employee_data)  

    # Define the main function to create the GUI elements and start the event loop
    def employee_btn_func():
        global employee_subwindow
        global checkbox_canvas

        # Create the GUI elements to display the data
        employee_subwindow = Canvas(win, background="#f0f0f0", width=1050, height=525, borderwidth=0,
                                    highlightthickness=0)
        employee_subwindow.place(x=420, y=215)

        checkbox_canvas = Canvas(win, background="#f0f0f0", width=50, height=525, borderwidth=0,
                                 highlightthickness=0)
        checkbox_canvas.place(x=380, y=215)

        # Retrieve the data and update the GUI element(s) initially
        update_employee_data()

        # Create the checkbox feature
        cursor3.execute("SELECT id_number FROM employees")
        result3 = cursor3.fetchall()

        var_list = []
        for saa, row in enumerate(result3):
            var1 = StringVar(value=row[0], name=row[0])
            style = ttk.Style()
            style.configure("Vertical.TCheckbutton", padding=(0, 4))
            checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(checkbox_canvas, variable=var1, cursor="hand2", style="Vertical.TCheckbutton")
            checkbox.grid(row=saa, column=0)
            var_list.append(var1)

        def view_profile():
            id_list = [var.get() for var in var_list if
                       var.get()]  # contains the id's of the checkboxes, and for every checked checkbox, the original value which is the id changes to "1"
            id_list_backup = [value for row in result3 for value in
                              row]  # contains the constant assigned id's of every checkbox
            for xz in range(len(id_list)):  # loops through the id_list to see if 1 is inside the list
                if id_list[xz] == '1':  # if 1 is inside the list, the index of the value 1 is taken and is matched
                    taken_id = id_list_backup[xz]
                    cursor2.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id_number=%s",
                                    (taken_id,))  # which is the assigned id
                    data = cursor2.fetchall()
                    print(data)  

        view_btn = Button(text="view", command=view_profile)
        view_btn.place(x=400, y=400)

        refreshbtn = Button(text="add", command=update_employee_data)
        refreshbtn.place(x=440, y=400)

        # Schedule the refresh function to update the GUI element(s) periodically
        win.after(10000, refresh_employee_data)
```

Whenever the refresh button gets pressed, the button click gets registered so I assumed that the refresh itself works, maybe? But the display does not change at all. Where does the issue lie and what can I do to fix it? Please help, thank you.

Comment: You need a process's that checks every 100 millis condos or so if there is new data

Comment: Note that `employee_subwindow.delete("all")` will not clear the canvas (I don't know why canvas is used) because those entry boxes are put in the canvas using `grid()`.

Comment: Post a [mre]. You are refreshing every 10 second. Did you mean it? And are you sure the first 10 records of the ```employees``` table are updated?